# Popup event for specific GeoJSON layer in Leaflet

Tags: polygon, leaflet, geojson, popup

Consider the following Leaflet map construction, which utilizes tiles from OSM and plots two GeoJSON files. The first GeoJSON file is derived from a multipolygon shapefile and the second GeoJSON file is a point shapefile. The relevant code is as follows.

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.addEventListener("click", () => {
            layer.bringToFront();
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.town);
        });
     }

     var mapstyle = {
        zoomControl: true,
        layers: [tileLayer],
        maxZoom: 14,
        minZoom: 8
     }

     var polystyle = {
        color: 'black',      // Outline color
        weight: 2,          // Outline width
        opacity: 1,         // Outline opacity (0 to 1)
        fillOpacity: 0,    // Fill opacity (0 to 1)
        interactive: 'false'
     }
     var markeroptions = {
        radius: 5,
        fillColor: 'blue',
        color: '#000000',
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.0,
        interactive: 'true'
     }
     var tileLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
     var map = L.map('map', mapstyle
     ).on('load', onMapLoad).setView([40.93920434539264, -73.86905931034256], 11);
     fetch('link/to/file/points.json')
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => {
          L.geoJSON(data, {style: polystyle}).addTo(map);
     });
     fetch('link/to/file/points.json')
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => {
          L.geoJSON(data, {
                pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                     return L.circleMarker(latlng, markeroptions);
                }, onEachFeature: onEachFeature
          }).addTo(map);
     });
     function onMapLoad(){
          console.log("map loaded");
     }
```

The entirety of this code produces the desired result, with the exception of the bindPopup at each circleMarker centroid. The issue I'm facing is that these popups do not fire when clicking on a point located inside a layer polygon. This issue looks as follows, note that the popup successfully fires over a point outside the polygon GeoJSON, but fails to do so just to the east:

[image]

What corrections can be made to the code above to allow popup events to fire on circleMarkers found inside the boundaries of any particular polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Leaflet ordering of layers on the map (`zIndex` order) is controlled with map panes (see https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-pane and https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/). Different type of layers (tile layers, vector layers etc) are by default assigned to different standard map panes, where each pane has it's own `zIndex` value.

For example, all vector layers are assigned to `overlayPane` with `zIndex` 400. But it is possible to create custom map pane with desired `zIndex` and assign layer to that pane. This is done with the `pane` option.

So in your case you just create map pane with `zIndex` value of 450 to place it above standard `overlayPane` and assign circle markers to that pane.

Also on your `onEachFeature` function your are assigning popup to layer after each click on marker. This means popup will be shown only after second click. There is no need for `layer.addEventListener("click"` handling, `layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.town);` is anough

So relevant part of the code could look something like this:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.town);
}

var markeroptions = {
  pane: 'pointsPane',
  radius: 5,
  fillColor: 'blue',
  color: '#000000',
  weight: 1,
  opacity: 1,
  fillOpacity: 0.0,
  interactive: 'true'
};

map.createPane('pointsPane');
map.getPane('pointsPane').style.zIndex = 450;

fetch('link/to/file/points.json')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  L.geoJSON(data, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
      return L.circleMarker(latlng, markeroptions);
    },
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
  }).addTo(map);
});
```

Comment: This answer has been very insightful, I appreciate it! I've implemented the additions, but I still don't have the popups triggering on these points inside the polygons. I've tried increasing the z-index to 1000, does this issue relate to how the popups trigger in the onEachFeature function?

Comment: My mistake, map pane should be assigned to circle markers. See modified answer.

Comment: That solves it, also great catch on the OnClick event listener being an extraneous step in the function. I'll accept your answer, thanks for your help!